# Problem with registering multiple users in my app

Tags: c++

I created this program, it is a simple login and registration program in C++. It is working fine, but it has a small problem in that it only works for 1 user. When I register an account and try to login, it works fine, but when I create a 2nd account and try to login, the 2nd account doesn't login. It will only login for the 1st account which has been stored.  In a data file, it stores all data of the 2nd account, like password and username, but it doesn't login.  Can anyone help me with this problem?

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<windows.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string Register_Name, Register_Password,Name,Password,Check_Name, Check_Password;
Menue:
    system("color 1f");
    system("cls");
    string select;
    cout<<"Enter 1 for Create account\n";
    cout<<"\nEnter 2  for Login account\n";
    cout<<"\nEnter 3  for Exite\n\n";
    cin>>select;
    if(select=="1")
    {
        system("cls");
        system("color 2f");
        cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\tCreate Account";
        std::ofstream create_account;
        create_account.open("data.txt",ios::out|std::ios::app);
        cout<<"\n\n\n"<<"New Username: "; 
        cin>>Register_Name;
        cout<<"\nNew Password: ";
        cin>>Register_Password;
        create_account<<"Name is         "<<Register_Name<<'\n';
        create_account<<"password is\t"<<Register_Password<<'\n'<<'\n';
        create_account.close();
        system("cls");
        system("color 3f");
        cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\tAccount Created";
        Sleep(5*400);
        goto Menue;
    }
    else
    {
        if(select=="2")
        {
            Login:
                system("cls");
                system("color 4f");
                cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\tLogin";
                std::ifstream Login;
                Login.open("data.txt",ios::out|std::ios::app);
                Login.ignore(16,'\n');
                getline(Login,Check_Name, '\n');
                Login.ignore(11,'\t');
                getline(Login,Check_Password, '\n');
                Login.close();
                cout<<"\n\n\n"<<"Enter Username: ";
                cin>> Name;
                cout<<"Enter Password: ";
                cin>> Password;
                if (Name==Check_Name && Password==Check_Password)
                {
                    system("cls");
                    system("color 5f");
                    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\tLogin Successful\n"<<"\n\n"<<"Welcome, "<<Name<<"\n";
                    system("pause");
                    goto Menue;
                }
                else
                {
                    system("color 6f");
                    system("cls");
                    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\tincorrect name or password\n";
                    Sleep(5*400);
                    goto Login;
                }
        }
        else
        {
            if(select=="3")
            {
                system("color 8f");
                system("cls");
                cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\tGood Bye";
                Sleep(5*400);
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                system("color 9f");
                system("cls");
                cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\tInvalid Selection";
                Sleep(5*400);
                goto Menue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your login works only for the 1st account because you are reading only the 1st account from the input file.  You are not reading subsequent accounts at all.

You read the 1st account from the file, then close the file, and then compare the user's input to the read values.  If the user does not enter matching credentials, you loop back around to reopen the input file, read only the 1st account, close the file, and compare the user's input - again and again - until the user *finally* enters credentials that match with the 1st account in the file.

You need to instead prompt the user for their credentials, and then loop through the *entire file* comparing *every account* in the file until you find a match, or reach EOF.  THEN, you can tell the user the outcome and act accordingly.

Also, on a side note, when you are opening the input file, you are specifying the `ios::out` and `std::ios::app` flags, which don't belong there. You should be using those flags only for input, not for input at all.

With that said, it would be really helpful for you to break out your individual operations into separate functions.  That will really cleanup the code and make it much more readable and manageable.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>

void ClearScreen()
{
    std::system("cls");
}

void SetScreenColor(const std::string &value)
{
    std::string cmd = "color " + value;
    std::system(cmd.c_str());
}

void SkipLine(std::istream &in)
{
    in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}

void WaitSeconds(DWORD Seconds)
{
    Sleep(Seconds * 1000);
}

void DisplayMsg(const std::string &color, const std::string &message)
{
    ClearScreen();
    SetScreenColor(color);
    std::cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t" << message << '\n';
}

void DisplayErr(const std::string &message)
{
    DisplayMsg("4f", message);
    WaitSeconds(2);
}

int Menu()
{
    int select;

    do
    {
        ClearScreen();
        SetScreenColor("1f");

        std::cout << "Enter 1 for Create account\n\n";
        std::cout << "Enter 2 for Login account\n\n";
        std::cout << "Enter 3 for Exite\n\n";
        std::cout << "Choice: ";

        if (std::cin >> select)
        {
            SkipLine(std::cin);

            if (select >= 1 && select <= 3)
                break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cin.clear();
            SkipLine(std::cin);
        }

        DisplayErr("Invalid Selection");
    }
    while (true);

    return select;
}

void CreateAccount()
{
    std::string Name, Password;

    DisplayMsg("2f", "Create Account\n\n");

    std::cout << "New Username: "; 
    std::getline(std::cin, Name);

    std::cout << "New Password: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, Password);

    std::ofstream data_file("data.txt", std::ios::app);
    if (!data_file)
    {
        DisplayErr("Can't create/open data file");
        return;
    }

    data_file << "Name is         " << Name << '\n';
    data_file << "Password is     " << Password << '\n';
    data_file << '\n';

    if (!data_file)
    {
        DisplayErr("Can't update data file");
        return;
    }

    DisplayMsg("3f", "Account Created");
    WaitSeconds(2);
}

void Login()
{
    std::string Name, Password, Check_Name, Check_Password;

    do
    {
        DisplayMsg("4f", "Login\n\n");

        std::cout << "Enter Username: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, Name);

        std::cout << "Enter Password: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, Password);

        std::ifstream data_file("data.txt");
        if (!data_file)
        {
            DisplayErr("Can't open data file");
            return;
        }

        while (data_file.ignore(16) &&
               std::getline(data_file, Check_Name) &&
               data_file.ignore(16) &&
               std::getline(data_file, Check_Password))
        {
            if (Name == Check_Name && Password == Check_Password)
            {
                DisplayMsg("5f", "Login Successful");
                std::cout << "\n\n" << "Welcome, " << Name << '\n';
                std::system("pause");
                return;
            }

            SkipLine(data_file);
        }

        DisplayErr("incorrect name or password");
    }
    while (true);
}

int main()
{
    int select;

    do
    {
        select = Menu();

        switch (select)
        {
            case 1:
                CreateAccount();
                break;

            case 2:
                Login();
                break;
        }
    }
    while (select != 3);

    DisplayMsg("8f", "Good Bye");
    WaitSeconds(2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Adeelzaman786 You already know how to run a loop (though you *really* should not be using `goto` for that!), and you already know how to read the first 2 lines from the file. So what is stopping you from simply adding another loop to read the first 2 lines, then the next 2 lines, and so on? Please at least *attempt* to solve this yourself before asking for someone to just write the code for you